# How to handle error: nested generic parameters is never used

Tags: rust, traits

Trying to use T as generic parameter of a trait of another generic parameter [this way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=04c32b88e0286d54a664c9c5b428dddc):

```rust
pub trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo() -> T;
}

struct Bar<T, F: Foo<T>> {
    f: F,
}

fn main() {
}
```

Failing with:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:5:12
  |
5 | struct Bar<T, F: Foo<T>> {
  |            ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

The compiler advice is to use [`PhantomData`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5529716e2421c45777923c3322189124):

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo() -> T;
}

struct Bar<T, F: Foo<T>> {
    f: F,
    t: PhantomData<T>,
}

fn main() {
}
```

Isn't there a more elegant way to deal with this than creating a fake field with a strangely named traits?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer this question in the abstract. What characteristics should `struct Bar` have, should it implement `trait Foo`?

Comment: No, it only needs a field that implements Foo.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question is actually pretty bad. As a consequence, one need to instantiate the fields with PhantomType each time you instantiate the structure.